# Generating MPEG DASH videos which are compilant with HbbTV 1.5 standard

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

I am looking for a the command line options for ffmpeg, DASHEncoder and MP4Box to generate HbbTV 1.5 compilant MPEG DASH videos.

See http://www.hbbtv.org/pages/about_hbbtv/specification.php for more information on the HbbTV 1.5 standard and its DASH profile which is used there.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to DASH-streaming for HbbTV 1.5 devices, the input arguments for FFmpeg and MP4Box depend on each other. Options to encode a video with FFmpeg for HbbTV terminals could be

```
FFmpeg -i input.avi -f h264 -c:v libx264 -aspect 16:9 -preset slow -profile:v high -r 50 -g 100 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -b:v 3584k -maxrate 3584k -bufsize 7168k -x264opts nal-hrd=vbr -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -ar 48k -ac 2 output.mp4
```

In order to make sure that the video will be played back smoothly, the arguments for the bitrate and maxrate of the video should be the same. In addition, the bufsize argument should not be bigger then twice the bitrate.

The arguments for the the GOP and force_key_frames options depend on the length of segments you create with MP4Box.
It is recommended that each segment starts with a keyframe and that one segment includes an entire GOP. in this example, the length for each segment should be at least 2 seconds, or a multiple of 2 seconds.

Options to segment the encoded video could be

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -frag 2000 -rap -profile live -segment-name video$Number$ -segment-ext m4s -out video.mpd input.mp4#video:id=1
MP4Box -dash 2000 -frag 2000 -rap -profile live -segment-name audio$Number$ -segment-ext m4s -out audio.mpd input.mp4#audio:id=2
```

Now each segment and each fragment within the segment has a length of 2 seconds. The required profile for HbbTV devices is the live profile.

If you are looking for adaptive MPEG-DASH or legacy test streams for HbbTV devices, you can find a wide variaty of testcases by following this link: http://av-standard.irt.de/wiki/index.php/Referenzclips